# How can i make two pages access the same list on ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, list, components

here i have a Page that takes the data from **const offerte** and create as many `<MarketDiv>` component as the data that is inside the **const offerte.**
The thing is that i have another page where theres a form to fill and the data should be saved in the list so it can dynamic create a new component, so my question is :  How can i add element to this list from another page? Do i have to create a different type of List? Because i cant put them in the same page , they dont let me do it (my job).

```
class AttivaCommunity extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const offerte = [
            {titolo:"Community - Quote for API",costo:"99€",descrizione:"sono creato dinamicamente",attività:"Prodotto",assets:"Competence"},
            {titolo:"Community - Quote for API",costo:"9999999€",descrizione:"sono creato dinamicamente",attività:"Prodotto",assets:"Competence"},
            {titolo:"Community - Quote for API",costo:"999999999999€",descrizione:"sono creato dinamicamente",attività:"Prodotto",assets:"Competence"}
        ];
        return(
            <div>
                <Container fluid className="MainPageRow2">
                    <Row className="Col_margin py-1 px-1">
                        {offerte.map((offerta)=> <MarketDiv titolo={offerta.titolo} costo={offerta.costo} descrizione={offerta.descrizione} attività={offerta.attività} assets={offerta.assets}/>)}
                    </Row>
                </Container>  
            
            </div> 

            )
        }
                    
    }
export default AttivaCommunity
```